Create a visual studio test playlist from a list of test names
I have a list of test names (obtained from git changes, it's all the tests that I have modified in one way or another during this development).
I want to turn this list into a Visual Studio test playlist.
I could search for each test name, right-click, add to playlist. But the list is (very) long: how could I simply add all the tests to one playlist?

1.Right-click on any test and choose Add to Playlist > New Playlist.
2.Save the playlist with an appropriate name. This will create a .playlist XML file in your project folder.
3.In the .playlist file, use rule element to config the playlist.
Here is an example:
   <!-- Match="Any": Specifies that any of the conditions within the current level must be met.-->
   <!-- Match="All": Specifies that all conditions within the current level must be met.-->
<!-- The Property element is used to specify the criteria for matching tests.-->
<Playlist Version="2.0">
 <Rule Name="Includes" Match="Any">
   <!-- Rule 1: Match the project -->
   <Rule Match="All">
     <Property Name="Solution" />
     <Rule Match="Any">
       <!-- Match a specific project -->
       <Rule Match="All">
         <Property Name="Project" Value="ConsoleApp2" />
         <Rule Match="Any">
           <!-- Match a specific namespace -->
           <Rule Match="All">
             <Property Name="Namespace" Value="MyNamespace" />
             <Rule Match="Any">
               <!-- Match a specific class -->
               <Rule Match="All">
                 <Property Name="Class" Value="MyFirstTestClass" />
                 <Rule Match="Any">
                   <!-- Match specific test methods -->
                   <Rule Match="All">
                     <Property Name="TestWithNormalizedFullyQualifiedName" Value="MyFirstTestClass.Test1" />
                     <Rule Match="Any">
                       <Property Name="DisplayName" Value="MyFirstTestClass.Test1" />
                     </Rule>
                   </Rule>
                   <Rule Match="All">
                     <Property Name="TestWithNormalizedFullyQualifiedName" Value="MyFirstTestClass.Test2" />
                     <Rule Match="Any">
                       <Property Name="DisplayName" Value="MyFirstTestClass.Test2" />
                     </Rule>
                   </Rule>
                 </Rule>
               </Rule>
             </Rule>
           </Rule>
         </Rule>
       </Rule>
     </Rule>
   </Rule>
 </Rule>
</Playlist>


This is not really helping: My test are in different namespaces and classes, so I would have to dig up the properties of each of my test to manually complete the file (While on the other hand, search on the test explorer can search all namespaces) : in the end, it is not faster than search on test explorer

I understand your point. I want to clarify that the example I provided is more complex to fully demonstrate how each level filters. In reality, you can directly match class names or method names, as long as you clearly specify them in the Property Name. If this doesn't improve efficiency, you'll have to use your previous method.





